# vim: search and replace for "&"

Tags: vim

In order to replace each occurrence of "&" to "&&" in the range from the current line to 30 more lines on, I issue `:.,+30s/\\&/\\&\\&/g` but Vim says "Pattern not found". I'm escaping the special character "&" by double backslash "\".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try not escaping everything - `:.,+30s/&/&&/g` seems to work for me.

Comment: To clarify: this is not because `&` is not a metacharacter: while in pattern it is true (unless `&` was escaped or very-magic mode was activated), in replacement string `&` means the same as `\0`: the whole matched substring. As “the whole matched substring” is an ampersand itself, this solution works. Note also that if 'magic' option was turned off, the statement “& in replacement represents the whole matched pattern” is false in a number of commands including `:s`.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to escape the ampersand in the first part of a regular expression. It only has special meaning in the second (replace) part.

You are looking for patterns that say "\&" and replace them with patterns that say "\&\&".

The simple way to replace is just:

```
:.,+30s/&/&&/g
```

Answer (score 4):

It can also be useful remark that if you need to change the **&** position for example: `_&` to `&_` the **&** has to be escaped only in the replace statements of the substitute expression:

```
:.,+30s/ &/\& /g
           ^
```